# Adding elements to the beginning of a multidimensional array and pushing the other elements to the next row PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add elements to a multidimensional array, but I also actually want to push the other elements to the next row when I do that, but right now I'm only able to have them on the same row. Please take a look:

```
$array[0][0] = "one";
$array[0][1] = "two";
$array[1][0] = "three";
$array[1][1] = "four";

et($array); <--- Function to echo an array in the table format
```

output:

```
|one   |two | 
|three |four|
```

adding an element to the beginning of the array, and echoing it out:

```
array_unshift($array[0] , 'zero');
et($array);
```

output:

```
|zero  |one |two| 
|three |four|   |
```

the output I'm trying to get:

```
|zero |    | 
|one  |two |  
|three|four|
```

Is there any way to get the element to be added to the first row, and push the other elements to the second row in a multidimensional array? If there is, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: `array_unshift($array, ["zero", ""]);` Maybe?!, Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: @Rizier123 Nope. There's a parse error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/a8332431/public_html/test4.php on line 8

Comment: That's a PHP version problem.

Comment: Your php version is then < 5.4 just change out `[]` with `array()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepend a new array onto the existing array:

```
array_unshift($array, array('zero'));
```

Or depending on what your `et()` function expects:

```
array_unshift($array, array('zero', ''));
```

Or maybe you need a `&nbsp;` to render the cell correctly.  Not sure without the code.

Comment: Little special hint: `|zero |[second coloumn here]|` :)

Comment: Depends on whether their `et()` function requires that.

Comment: The output only has one column: zero|one|three|

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think it will automatically fill missing elements

Comment: @iscattered Then just add an empty element in the array, e.g. `array_unshift($array , array('zero', ''));`